# Inserting None value into Date column from python to PostgreSQL database using PygreSQL v5.0.6

Tags: python, postgresql, pygresql

I am struggling to insert `None` values into the date column of a PostgreSQL database from python using PygreSQL v5.0.6.

Some code:

```
def _update_traits_db(self, code, date_start, date_end, unit):
    sql = ("Insert into traits (code, date_start, date_end, unit) "
           "VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') "
           "ON CONFLICT (code) DO UPDATE "
           "SET date_start = excluded.date_start, date_end = excluded.date_end, unit = excluded.unit "
           % (code, date_start, date_end, unit))
    try:
        self._connect()
        self._cur.execute(sql)
        self._con.commit()
        self._close()
    except Exception as e:
        self._close()
        raise e
```

There are a couple issues I am facing, the biggest being the the possibility of `None` values for `date_end` and `unit`, the first being a date causing SQL errors like:

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "None"
>   LINE 1: ...d, unit) VALUES ('AWGHT', '2003-01-29T23:00:00Z', 'None', 'N...
>                                                                    ^
>   If I replace the none value with a hardcoded NULL then it works but from reading around I figured it should be handled py PyGreSQL automatically converting `None` to NULL but I can't get that to work.

A second issue is with `None` values in the `unit` column, this is supposed to be a string but `None` is now stored in the database where it ideally would be a NULL value. I have tried removing the quotes from the around the '%s' for unit in the query vut that only causes SQL error on the None value.

I am fairly new to Python and PostgreSQL so there are many potential places i might have messed up so all suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: You don't need the `'`s around the placeholders... just use `%s` by itself... eg: `values (%s, %s, %s, %s)` - the engine will already correctly escape strings, None will be converted to null etc...

Comment: Tried this now, but am getting an error on the date due to the date format i believe, the date input is this " 2003-01-29T23:00:00Z" so i get ERROR:  syntax error at or near "T23"

Comment: So your date is a string then? If you make it a `datetime` object instead - it'll work fine.

Comment: Have converted the date strings to datetime objects and that works and can be inserted into the database, I cant find a way to convert a "None" variable to a datetime though and for some reason its still not converted into NULL when i try inserting it to the database. Same thing goes for the "Unit" value.

Comment: After removing the quotes around the values like @JonClements sugested i also get an error on the code column. "ERROR:  column "testCode" does not exist" so it does not seem to escape the strings on its own.

Comment: Is it definitely a `None` object and not a string containing "None"... eg `type(obj)` gives you a `NoneType`

Comment: print(type(date_end)) prints this: <class 'NoneType'> when theres no value for date_end

Comment: Okay... I'd have thought the adaptor should handle the `None` -> `NULL` just fine... although it's not listed as a conversion at http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pg/adaptation.html. I have only ever used psycopg2 when dealing with postgres.

Comment: I have never used psycopg2, have just started with python and postrgreSQL so i just jumped at the first thing i found that seemed straight forward. Is psycopg2 a better library to to use?

Comment: it's the one that's most widely used by various frameworks and in production systems...

Comment: Excellent, I will give that a go then. Thanks a lot for your time anyhow and hopefully it will be easier to get working properly with psycopg2!

Comment: you're welcome... it's probably overkill for now, but you might find it worthwhile looking at https://www.sqlalchemy.org/ - if you want to move to ORM stuff later you can, but you can still use it as a wrapper around the database adapters and execute raw queries as you're doing now if needs be (but can also use it to construct queries  programatically if needs be as well)

Comment: ahh... I'd missed that you had a `%` in there for interpolation - Parfait's given you the answer - everything should just work with that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use parameterization, the industry standard to separate SQL code from data values, and not string interpolation which looks similar since the placeholder `%s` is used in both. With this approach, `None` should resolve as `NULL`. In fact, [PygreSQL docs](http://www.pygresql.org/contents/pg/adaptation.html) even warns users on the practice:

> Warning 
>  Remember to **never** insert parameters directly into your queries
>   using the % operator. Always pass the parameters separately.

Consider following adjustment using unquoted `%s` placeholders (see [docs](http://www.pygresql.org/contents/tutorial.html#first-steps-with-the-db-api-2-0-interface)) with values later binded in `cursor.execute()` call:

```
def _update_traits_db(self, code, date_start, date_end, unit):
    # PREPARED STATEMENT (NO DATA VALUES INTERPOLATED)
    sql =  """INSERT INTO traits (code, date_start, date_end, unit)
              VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)
              ON CONFLICT (code) DO UPDATE
              SET date_start = excluded.date_start, 
                  date_end = excluded.date_end, 
                  unit = excluded.unit
           """
    try:
        self._connect()
        # BIND PARAMETERS WITH TUPLE OF VALUES
        self._cur.execute(sql, (code, date_start, date_end, unit))
        self._con.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    finally:
        self._close()
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot to both of you! Seems i had a misunderstanding on how the parameterization in python really worked, this makes a lot more sense. Glad to have that cleared up, thanks!

Comment: Great to hear. Yes, this `cursor.execute(query, params)` approach is consistent across most Python DB-APIs (cxOracle, ibmdb, pymssql, pyodbc, pymysql, psycopg2, sqlite3) per Python's [PEP 249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) SQL standard. Also, parameterization is an industry-wide best practice not just in Python but any app layer language (Java, C#, PHP, Perl, etc.) running SQL. Happy coding!